# iOS Scroll images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

After looking for tutorials, and see a lot of answers about scroll images, i have difficulties to implement a UIScrollView like in the choice of character in Lane Splitter.
In this scroll, the area that interested me is the little images. I want to make the same.

Another example that interested me should be the coverflow from Itunes, but without the images on the left and right. Just the image on center, and the same animation.

Thanks for your help ! =)

Comment: Very few people will know what Lane Splitter is. Post a picture of what effect you want exactly.

Comment: The problem is that i have few reputation to post a picture :/ Please improve it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(id)init{
   self = [super init];
   if (self){
     UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 155, 265, 180)];
        [scroller setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [scroller setPagingEnabled:YES];
        [scroller setDelegate:self];
        [self addSubview:scroller];

     NSArray *arrayOfImages = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects images, nil];
}

-(void)setScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scroller1 :(NSArray *)array{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = scroller.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = scroller.frame.size;

        UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
        newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        newPageView.frame = frame;
        [scroller addSubview:newPageView];

    }

    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroller.frame.size.width * array.count, scroller.frame.size.height);
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setScrollView:scroller :arrayOfImages];
}
```

I believe this should work. It is a scrollview and insert uiimageviews

Comment: This works fine ! I've put a UIButton, which permits to scroll of image. Here is the code for :                                                   -(void)ActionScroll
{
    X = test*265;
    [scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(X, 0) animated:YES];
    test++;
}